# Separable first order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following ODE without using Power Series. Suppose $a,b$, and $c$ any constants other than zero.

$$y'=ay+be{^{-y}}+c$$

I know it is separable but I can't find the integral $$\int\frac{1}{ay+be^{-y}+c}dy$$

Is there any hidden trick to make the equation more easy with integral?

Comment: Not all integrals have a closed form. Likewise, not all DEs have closed form solutions. You've likely hit that here.

Comment: In first I thought this integral will be  computed by some tricks , but after too many tries , I couldn't be sure it hasn't closed form. Thanks

Comment: Mathematica can't take it, so it's likely the antiderivative doesn't exist in closed form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separable doesn't mean the integral(s) you arrive at can be computed in closed form. Do you have a reason to believe this should be possible in your example?

Comment: Indeed , I don't , I just need someone to confirm for me this cannot be computed in closed form and this what you did. Thanks